# Correct way to perform backup of Cassandra/Scylladb

Tags: backup, cassandra, scylladb

What's the correct(advisable) method to backup a cassandra or scylladb so that we can restore it on development environment with ease?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Scylla, please look at the following official documentation:

- [Backup your Data](http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/backup/)

  > - Full Backup Snapshots are taken using `nodetool snapshot`.
  > - Enabling the incremental backup (disabled by default) will create a hard-link from each SSTable, right after it is flushed, to a backups directory.
  >     For a complete point in time backup you need: a snapshot plus incremental backups and commit logs since that time of the snapshot. Make sure to clean unnecessary incremental backup, Scylla will not do it for you.
- [Restore from a Backup and Incremental Backup](http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/restore/)

  > Restoring a keyspace from backup requires all snapshot files of the tables, and incremental backup files taken after the snapshot - if available. Before restoring from backup, you should truncate the table data, making sure existing data will not override the restored one.

  See the linked documentation for detailed instructions.

Answer (score -1):

In Cassandra we can take full backup from below command.
**nodetool snapshot**
A snapshot first flushes all in-memory writes to disk, then makes a hard link of the SSTable files for each keyspace. You must have enough free disk space on the node to accommodate making snapshots of your data files. A single snapshot requires little disk space. However, snapshots can cause your disk usage to grow more quickly over time because a snapshot prevents old obsolete data files from being deleted. After the snapshot is complete, you can move the backup files to another location if needed, or you can leave them in place.

We can also take snapshot for keysapce and table as well. Apart full backup we can enable incremental backup(incremental_backups) on cassandra.yaml also by default it is false.

You can refer below link for more details.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupTakesSnapshot.html

To restore snpashot is cassandra is very easy.however in cassandra multiple scenario for restoration. To restore a node from snapshot just copy the all sstables from snapshot folder to actual data folder after clearing the data and take restart cassandra services. it will restore the data to previous version of data.you can copy also incremental sstable also to actual data folder if require point in time recovery.

Please refer more details on below link.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupIncremental.html